# PROC MEANS output as table

Tags: sas

I'm trying to export quartile information on a grouped dataset as a dataset in SAS but when I run this code my output is a table with the correct information displayed but the dataset WORK.TOP_1O_PERC is only summary statistics of the set (no quartiles).  Does anyone know how I can export this as the CLASS (PDX) and its 25th and 75th percentiles? Thanks!

```
PROC MEANS DATA=WORK.TOP_10_DX P25 P75;
CLASS PDX;
VAR AmtPaid;
OUTPUT OUT = WORK.TOP_10_PERC;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 4):

I like the STACKODS output that is a data set which is like the default printed output.

```
proc means data=sashelp.class n p25 p75 stackods;
   ods output summary=summary;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: `STACKODS` is one the most bestest `MEANS` options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `output` statement with `<statistics>=` options.

```
PROC MEANS DATA=WORK.TOP_10_DX NOPRINT;
  CLASS PDX;
  VAR AmtPaid;
  OUTPUT OUT = WORK.TOP_10_PERC P25=P25 P75=P75;
RUN;
```

Compared to `ods output`, `output` statement is much faster but less flexible with multiple analysis variables or `by` statement specified situation.